# Symfony2+Doctrine+Repository: Should not this function return the object instead of array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this function in my repository:

```
public function findLatestFeeAsigned($company_id) {
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('c', 'chw');
    $qb->from('Configuration\FeeBundle\Entity\Fee', 'c');
    $qb->leftJoin('Company\ApprovalBundle\Entity\CompanyHasWtax', 'chw', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.id = chw.wtax');
    $qb->where('chw.company = ?1');
    $qb->orderBy('chw.created', 'ASC');
    $qb->setMaxResults(1);
    $qb->setParameter(1, $company_id);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And I call it from my controller in this way:

```
$entityCurrentFee = $em->getRepository('ApprovalBundle:CompanyHasWtax')->findLatestFeeAsigned($id);
```

Where `$id` is a request parameter. Then I try to get the some column values as:

```
$entityCurrentFee->getId();
```

But I got error saying that `$entityCurrentFee` is not a object, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're querying by the primary key or just expecting to retrieve single object, you should use

```
$qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Beware that this function throws `NoResultException`

Comment: getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult() will avoid the no result exception if that is what he wants.